# Why do I retrieve null values in Postman from foreign key relationships fields in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Java with Spring Boot framework and MySQL (via Hibernate) database locally. I have 3 entities: Car, User and Purchase. Each purchase consists of purchaseId, user (takes data from its id in User Entity class), car (takes data from carId and Car Entity class) and description.

I am not sure if I established connections in the correct way. However it seems to be connected appropriately in the database. It is just frustrating that whenever I want to create a new object of purchase, I get null values for car and user, although I did specify its values in the POST request.

**Car** Entity

```
package IndividualProject.example.indproject.Entity;

import IndividualProject.example.indproject.Repository.CarService;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

@Entity
@Table (name = "car")
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column (name = "car_id")
    private int carId;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String brand;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 40)
    private String model;

    @Min(value=100)
    @Max(value=1000000)
    private int price;

    @Min(value=1900)
    @Max(value=2022)
    private int yearOfProduction;

    @Min(value = 10)
    @Max(value = 1000000)
    private int mileage;

    @Size(max = 60)
    private String location;

    @Size(max = 100)
    private String description;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "car")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Purchase purchase;

    public Car() {
    }

    public Car(int carId, String brand, String model, int price, int yearOfProduction, int mileage, String location, String description) {
        this.carId = carId;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.model = model;
        this.price = price;
        this.yearOfProduction = yearOfProduction;
        this.mileage = mileage;
        this.location = location;
        this.description = description;
    }


    public int getCarId() {
        return carId;
    }

    public void setCarId(int carId) {
        this.carId = carId;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getYearOfProduction() {
        return yearOfProduction;
    }

    public void setYearOfProduction(int yearOfProduction) {
        this.yearOfProduction = yearOfProduction;
    }

    public int getMileage() {
        return mileage;
    }

    public void setMileage(int mileage) {
        this.mileage = mileage;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

**User** Entity

```
package IndividualProject.example.indproject.Entity.Roles;
import IndividualProject.example.indproject.Entity.Purchase;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
@Entity
@Table( name = "users",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"),
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email")
        })
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true)
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column
    private String username;
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Email
    @Column
    private String email;
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 120)
    @Column
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    @Column
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "user")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private List<Purchase> purchases;


    public User() {
    }

    public User(String username, String email, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

**Purchase** Entity

```
package IndividualProject.example.indproject.Entity;

import IndividualProject.example.indproject.Entity.Roles.User;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table (name = "purchase")
public class Purchase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long purchaseId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_car_id", referencedColumnName = "car_id")
    @Setter
    private Car car;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String description;

    public Purchase() {
    }

    public Car getCar() {
        return car;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public Long getPurchaseId() {
        return purchaseId;
    }

    public void setPurchaseId(Long purchaseId) {
        this.purchaseId = purchaseId;
    }

    public Purchase(User user, Car car, String description){
        this.user = user;
        this.car = car;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

I tried adding request (POJO) classes as well.

**CarCreationRequest** POJO class

```
package IndividualProject.example.indproject.Entity.Request;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.validation.constraints.*;

@Data
public class CarCreationRequest {
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String brand;
    @NotBlank
    @Size (max = 30)
    private String model;
    @NotEmpty
    @Min(value = 100)
    @Max(value = 1000000)
    private int price;
    @NotEmpty
    @Min (value = 1900)
    @Max (value = 2022)
    private int yearOfProduction;
    @NotEmpty
    @Min (value = 100)
    @Max (value = 1000000)
    private int mileage;
    @NotBlank
    @Size (max = 60)
    private String location;
    @NotBlank
    @Size (max = 100)
    private String description;
}
```

**PurchaseRequest** POJO class

```
package IndividualProject.example.indproject.Entity.Request;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class PurchaseRequest {
     private int carCarId;
     private Long userId;
     private String description;
}
```

I also have repository interface for these entities.

**PurchaseInterface** Repository

```
package IndividualProject.example.indproject.Interface;

import IndividualProject.example.indproject.Entity.Purchase;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface PurchaseInterface extends JpaRepository<Purchase, Long> {
    Optional<Purchase> findById(Long purchaseId);

    @Transactional
    void deleteByUserId(int userId);
}
```

Afterwards, I use this data in the service layer.

**Purchase** Service

```
package IndividualProject.example.indproject.Repository;

import IndividualProject.example.indproject.Entity.Purchase;
import IndividualProject.example.indproject.Entity.Request.PurchaseRequest;
import IndividualProject.example.indproject.Interface.PurchaseInterface;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PurchaseService {

    @Autowired
    PurchaseInterface purchaseInterface;

    public List<Purchase> getPurchases() {return purchaseInterface.findAll();}
    public Purchase getPurchaseById(Long purchaseId) {return purchaseInterface.getById(purchaseId);}
    public Purchase createPurchase(PurchaseRequest purchaseRequest) {
        Purchase purchase = new Purchase();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(purchaseRequest, purchase);
        return purchaseInterface.save(purchase);
    }
    public String deletePurchase(Long purchaseId) {purchaseInterface.deleteById(purchaseId);
        return "Purchase removed";
    }
}
```

Finally, in the PurchaseControllers, I am setting up http requests.

**PurchaseController**

```
package IndividualProject.example.indproject.Controller;

import IndividualProject.example.indproject.Entity.Purchase;
import IndividualProject.example.indproject.Entity.Request.PurchaseRequest;
import IndividualProject.example.indproject.Repository.PurchaseService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.RequestEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/purchase")
public class PurchaseController {

    @Autowired
    PurchaseService purchaseService;

    @GetMapping("/listOfPurchases")
    public List<Purchase> getPurchases() {return purchaseService.getPurchases();}

    @GetMapping("/{purchaseId}")
    public Purchase getPurchaseById(@PathVariable Long purchaseId) {return (Purchase) purchaseService.getPurchaseById(purchaseId);}

    @PostMapping("/createPurchase")
    public Purchase createPurchase(@RequestBody PurchaseRequest purchaseRequest) {
        return purchaseService.createPurchase(purchaseRequest);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/deletePurchase/{purchaseId}")
    public String deleteCar(@PathVariable Long purchaseId) {return purchaseService.deletePurchase(purchaseId);}
}
```

For testing purposes, I use Postman.

[Creating Purchase Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Ga9.jpg)

As you can see the response is fine. However, I am receiving null values for "user" and "car" fields. I also checked the connection in my database of foreign keys for car and user and it is set correctly. So my assumption is that I am either missing some part of the code or perhaps I might have some typo or wrong connection between databases.

[Purchase table in MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEjqD.jpg)

Comment: i guess the error here is `BeanUtils.copyProperties(purchaseRequest, purchase);` because the request type are other data types as the same names from purchase object .... there will be copied nothing. You must load there the real car and user and put it in the purchase than save

Comment: Thank you so much for taking a look. I searched on stackoverflow and I have a rough overview of the issue. However, I am stil unsure on where should I copy and load the car and user object. It would be great if you'd make a longer explaination. Thanks in advance @pL4Gu33

Comment: I guess the user and car already exists? That means you can load both via your ids in `createPurchase` and than use the Purchase constructor to add them there. There is no need for `BeanUtils.copyProperties`. You can also think and read about if you really need bi-directional relations in this but its your design decision :)